# How to pull array items into a variable in mongo

Tags: mongodb

How to pull array items into a variable:
so lets say this is my document:

```
{
    name: 'Vor',
    nums: [1,2,3,4,5]
}
```

how to create an array that will hold all of this items?

like `my_nums = ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, isn't it just:
var my_nums = doc.nums
?